# UNIX 'ls' command exclude wildcard

Tags: unix, ls

I have files a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 and I need to exclude a2 and b2 from the list using `ls` command only.

Comment: When I type ls --ignore="*2", it works but (assuming I have other files) when I type ls -a* -b* --ignore="*2", no files are excluded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ls [a-b][13]
a1  a3  b1  b3
```

Or

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls !(*2)
a1  a3  b1  b3
```

Answer (score 14):

use --ignore option

```
ls --ignore=[ab]2
```

Comment: But on what version of `ls` the option `--ignore` works? On my MAC it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm using Fefora13 if it helps.

Comment: My Mac OSX is not so advanced ;)

Comment: It's HW assignment and we are allowed to use ls only

Answer (score 2):

Just list the files you want:

```
ls a1 a3 b1 b3
```

Comment: +1 as this is the only way to satisfy the constraint "using ls only".  Any attempt to manipulate the argument list using shell globs is using the shell.  (Although, you use the shell to exec ls, so perhaps that particular constraint is ill-posed.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell, my thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try with ls and grep

```
ls -1 | grep -viw "a2\|b2"
```

Pay attention after ls a put 1 (the number one) and not the letter "l". Sometimes the font make them confusing.